# Examples of nonstable ∞-categories in which sifted colimits commute with finite limits

Tags: sheaf-theory, stable-homotopy, infinity-categories, limits-and-colimits, sites

What are some natural examples (if any) of nonstable ∞-categories in which finite limits commute with sifted colimits (or rather just colimits over Δ^op)?

Stable ∞-categories do satisfy this property, but are there any others?

(The application I have in mind involves a sheaf on the site of
smooth manifolds valued in some ∞-category, the finite limit is the descent object for some finite cover,
and the colimit over Δ^op is the realization of a simplicial object
obtained from the sheaf.)

Comment: Any $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ which admits a conservative, finite-limit preserving, and sifted colimit-preserving functor to a stable $\infty$-category will have the same property. For example, all sorts of structured ring spectra ($E_{\infty}$, $A_{\infty}$, etcetera...)

Comment: @JacobLurie: Thanks for the example!  I guess this applies in general to algebras over monads in stable ∞-categories whose functor preserves sifted colimits.